# Geometry Nodes - How does the Offset Scale parameter on the Extrude Mesh node work?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make various diamond-shaped panels with exact real-world dimensions.  I'm using Imperial dimensions in inches in my scene.  As an example, I start by adding a standard 24" x 24" x 24" cube and add a geometry node modifier.  In the geometry node editor, I use a Quadralateral node using the kite shape to get the outline, then using a Convex Hull to turn the edges into faces.  This creates two faces, one on the top and one on the bottom, but the object has zero thickness.  I then use Extrude Mesh with an Index node going into the Selection input of the Extrude Mesh node to only extrude the top face.

[image: Geometry Node Editor Screenshot]

Here's my problem.  I want the extruded object to be exactly 0.5" thick.  How can I calculate the proper Offset Scale to use?  I added a reference cube (the unselected wireframe in the screenshot) that is scaled down to 0.5" thick and then I manually adjusted the Offset Scale until the extruded object was 0.5" thick.  The value I need happens to be 0.0064.  But what is this value in relation to?  If I use 1.000 the extrusion is very long, way more than 0.5".  I'm guessing it's a ratio of some sort, but I cannot figure out what it is relating to.

So...how does the numeric value in Offset Scale work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (unit-less) "Blender units" are translated 1:1 when (by default) using metric units, so 1 Blender unit equals 1 m. And this is what the *Offset Scale* uses as well, an offset of 1.000 is 1 m when you are using metric units.

However, a 2 × 2 × 2 m default cube becomes a cube with side lengths of 78.7402" when you switch from *Metric* to *Imperial* with *Inches*, it is not changed into 2 × 2 × 2 inches or 2 × 2 × 2 feet or something. So it's

$$\frac{2\;m}{0.0254\frac{m}{in}}\approx78.7402\;in$$

And the *Extrude Mesh* node is still calculating with Blender units, so an *Offset Scale* of 1.000 is still 1 m, which means from *Offset Scale* to inches you have a factor of

$$\frac{1}{0.0254}\approx39.3701$$

so you can convert the value in inch by dividing with $39.3701$ to get the desired offset value or even simpler, multiply by $0.0254$:

[image: inch conversion]

For half an inch you get $0.5\cdot0.0254=0.0127$, actually I do not know how you got a value of $0.0064$. Is the scale on your object applied? It seems as if your object scale is 2, not 1. The *Geometry Nodes* internal values get scaled by the external factor which your object has in *Object Mode*.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for this explanation! Since I only use metric units, I never noticed this before, but I wonder why the nodes do not take over the set units of measure ...?

Comment: @quellenform I have no idea. Actually a slight change is there, the default cube is 2 m on each side and simply becomes 78.74 inches when you switch the units. However, if you add mesh primitives _after_ switching to _Imperial_, then a newly added cube has sides of 24" (= 2') length each.

Comment: @quellenform One idea: first of all just for convenience 1 Blender unit = 1 meter, because it is the easiest conversion and since Blender was created by people using metric units and they are easier to calculate to float since the sub-units are simple powers of ten. I guess internally it works with Blender units, and they are not converted 1:1 to Imperial to make it easier for example to append objects from one file to another and keeping relative proportions if they are modeled in real-life dimensions. Not that you append a 1 foot cube into a scene and it's the same size as a 1 meter cube.

Comment: Some correction from me: The Offset Scale doesn't use units at all, as it is a multiplier. **◆ Offset** vector can be interpreted as having an implicit meter unit. By default, the **◆ Offset** is the *Normal* field, and normals are normalized (duh), therefore they always have a length of $1$; here your explanation comes in, this 'unit-less' normal can be interpreted as described in meters (I would explain it differently, Blender calculates everything in *units*, when you enable metric system it just slaps a meter on every value, and imperial system applies a ratio)

Comment: So then this **◆ Offset** is multiplied (the same as Vector Math: Scale) by the *Offset Scale*. $1$ means no change. It's a convenience input that could easily be replaced by the Vector Math: Scale node (though then you couldn't use the implicit "Normal" and would need to add that node as well). I guess you can think of it as **◆ Offset** describing the direction, and *Offset Scale* describing the length, but it will only work if the **◆ Offset** is normalized…

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Feel free to add that in, I'm a bit busy right now. Sure, of course the scale is unit-less. Since he did not use the _Offset_ input and still wanted to know which relation his value had to the outcome I was oversimplifying to give him the ratio he was looking for.

Comment: Thanks @GordonBrinkmann. I'm just getting started with Geometry Nodes, so I'm still trying to get my head fully around your answer, but I'll fiddle around some more tonight after work.

One follow up - Your solution uses the original cube geometry to do a transform.  The node tree I posted actually ignores the added cube and generates geometry from scratch.  (The original cube is only used there as a reference.). Does that matter at all, i.e. needing to apply scale, etc.?

Comment: Some additional background, I'm using Geometry Nodes to generate a shape similar to a geodesic dome.  I added a cube to start, then added the GN modifier and ignored the input geometry completely.  I had the whole dome modeled and then went to add a person model to visualize the size, and I realized my dome was HUGE since my scale was messed up.  It was supposed to be about 20 feet in diameter but when I was hacking my way through GN I was creating reference circles with diameters of 2400" and it didn't occur to me at the time how wrong that was...

Comment: @fussylizard 2400" is definitely wrong, since 20' are only 240" no matter what Blender is doing when converting metric to Imperial units...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I'm working from some real-world plans, so I started by generating a panel to match the plan that I thought was the correct size (since I gave the size in inches as inputs to the Quadrilateral), then I fit everything else based on that.  Then later I realized the panel was way too big due to the scaling issues I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusvonBroady your comments helped clarify things.

Comment: One final issue I ran into while fixing things.  I had Value nodes feeding the inputs to a Quadrilateral, and apparently that is also in "Blender Units" which becomes meters.  So what I thought was 73" became 73 meters.  I had to multiple those values by 0.0254 before going into the quadrilateral to fix it.  But now my scaling issues are fixed.  Thanks all!